App Center is not working on a HP Compaq dx2300 Microtower
Whenever I try to open the App Center it starts to open, but then it closes. There's no crash or error message, and nothing I do changes anything. I think it's just the specs of the PC.
Report details:

Date generated:                              2024-09-22 19:57:53

Hardware information:

Hardware model:                              Hewlett Packard HP Compaq dx2300 Microtower
Memory:                                      2.0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel Core2 Duo E4600  × 2
Graphics:                                    Intel 946GZ (BW)
Disk capacity:                               250.1 GB
Firmware version:                           MS7336 1.12
OS name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
OS build:                                    (null)
OS type:                                     64-bit
GNOME version:                               46
Windowing system:                            Wayland
Kernel version:                              Linux 6.8.0-45-generic

